# CSS style to truncate long text doesnt work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need page title to be truncated with ellipsis if it is longer than the availbale space.

Demo - short title:

[image]

Demo - long title (css styling doesnt work):

[image]

All comments saying to add width - doesnt work either

[image]

Comment: add **width** property value to `.navbar-title`

Comment: Jordi Flores, tried that, no effect, besides, there is no fixed width, its responsive site

Comment: cale_b, picture is worth thousands words, is it not the code on the screenshots? if I posted this css rules, will you not be asking for a screenshot?

Comment: A jsfiddle would help.

Comment: I think this is quite a common question asked, in fact I'm going to start using this more in my work I think. Gives a much nicer UX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add your ellipsis styling to the `.navbar-header` instead, you also need to define a `width` or `max-width`, you can see this working on my [codepen](http://codepen.io/alexander-holman/pen/ALgxxr)

alternatively you can add `width` or `max-width` to the `.navbar-title` but as its an inline element you will need to change the `display` to `inline-block` too I believe.

Comment: This worked (defining css style for navbar-header)! adding width to navbar-title doesnt help

Comment: if you do it on the title you need to define a width and display for it, i've updated my codepen example to show you what i mean

Comment: however there is a problem, setting fixed width will deform the entire menu

Comment: you don't need to set a fixed with, just a width

Comment: I've updated my example to use a percentage width (100%) and you'll notice it works just fine in both cases :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Place the anchor tag inside a div.

```
<div class="title-div">
<a class="navbar-title">Some very long title</a>
</div>
```

The css should be as shown below:

```
.title-div
{
    max-width: 128px;
    overflow: hidden;    
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
}
.navbar-title
{
    white-space:nowrap !important;
}
```

Comment: This is on the right lines, but it's barely an answer, and should be a comment.

Comment: Let me refine it :)
Place the anchor tag inside a div.

<div class="title-div">
<a class="navbar-title ng-binding"></a>
</div>

The css should be as shown below:

.title-div
{
    max-width: 128px;
    overflow: hidden;    
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can actually shorten the titl, and add the three dots at the end, then save that as a class, and apply it to the heading tag.

But it requires that your container div have a width set, or else this will push it wider, which is what is happening.

```
.truncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/leecollingsco/Lq34xquf/1/

Comment: Yes I did read your post, did you look at my link? I think you want to wrap your `navbar-title` in a container, and give that a max width, which fits in the gap to the point where it doesn't cover your icons.

Comment: sure, thanks, sorry missed the link, though u just copy-pasted my css ))

Comment: I actually didn't see the other answer which also explains this, damn I thought I Was the first. Ah well :) hopefully that's reinforced the solution for you a bit more.

Comment: setting this style to navbar-header works on a title, but it deforms the entire navbar, since it should not have fixed width, its a responsive design

Comment: Well you'll need to monkey around with media queries, and maybe use max-width instead of width. But generally, that would be the idea. By the way, I didn't say give `navbar-header` a fixed width.. I said create a container within it just to wrap your `navbar-title`.

Answer (score -1):

```
div{
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap; 
overflow: hidden; 
width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: You should ideally explain your answer rather than just posting a code excerpt, or the original poster is unlikely to learn how to fix the issue.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.